# How to draw a normalized tangent arrow

Tags: graphics

I want to draw a *normalized* tangent arrow, so I use the `Normalize` command as follows:

```
tangent = 
  Table[{{t, Sin[t]}, {t, Sin[t]} + Normalize @ {1, Cos[t]}}, {t, -π, π, π/2}];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, 
  PlotRange -> 2, Epilog -> {Red, Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow /@ tangent}]
```

and I get this plot:

[image]

Seems good, but if take a close look at the length of the arrows, you'll see that the length is not normalized at all.
I've tried the `Show` and `Graphics` command instead of `Epilog`, but got the same plot.

Can someone tell me what I missed here?

Comment: Your plot is distorted by the default aspect ratio of `1/GoldenRatio`. Add `AspectRatio -> Automatic` to your plot options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue here is aspect ratio:
Using the following slight adaptation of your code:

```
tangent = 
  Table[{{t, Sin[t]}, {t, Sin[t]} + 
     Normalize@{1, Cos[t]}}, {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi], \[Pi]/2}];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> 2, 
 Epilog -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow /@ tangent}, 
   Circle[{#, Sin[#]}] & /@ Range[-\[Pi], \[Pi], \[Pi]/2]}]
```

[image]

However, specifying aspect ratio:

```
tangent = 
  Table[{{t, Sin[t]}, {t, Sin[t]} + 
     Normalize@{1, Cos[t]}}, {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi], \[Pi]/2}];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> 2, 
 Epilog -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow /@ tangent}, 
   Circle[{#, Sin[#]}] & /@ Range[-\[Pi], \[Pi], \[Pi]/2]}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

resolves matters:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another small question. Since many of the default values of options in _Mathematica_ is `Automatic`, Why WRI choose the default value of the `AspectRatio` as 1/`GoldenRatio`? I mean, why not choose `Automatic`, then in the algorithms(or in the front-end or something like that), `Automatic` use 1/`GoldenRatio` as default value? This seems more coherent to me.

Comment: @luyuwuli I am afraid I cannot answer that...as humans we make so many arbitrary decisions and adopt arbitrary conventions, August having 31 days, Julian v Gregorian calendar,  tau v pi as well as the countless debates in everyday life...I am sure there were reasons, like appeal of golden ratio to human aesthetics etc

Comment: Hahaha... Yes, I agree. I ask this because I've suffered a lot in the `AspectRatio` issue.

Comment: @luyuwuli, ["`AspectRatio` gives the ratio of width to height. Its default value is the inverse of the Golden Ratio–supposedly the most pleasing shape for a rectangle."](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/book/section-1.9.2)