# How can I add a tangent arrow at a certain point of a curve in a LogPlot?

Tags: plotting

How can I add an arrow at a certain point of a curve with the direction of the arrow tangential to that point? (Line are not straight in a log-plot.)

```
LogPlot[(1 - τ)^(-0.5),
 {τ, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.66, 20}},
 Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}},
 ImageSize -> 600,
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Thick]},
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 30},
 RotateLabel -> False,
 AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Relevant example code: [(56543)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56543/how-to-draw-a-normalized-tangent-arrow), [(22200)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22200/tangent-to-a-circle).

Comment: I think the fact that this Q concerns a `LogPlot` instead of `Plot`/`ParametricPlot` makes it sufficiently distinct from the related questions or proposed duplicate.  Certainly, the code in those questions does not work as is (without adjusting for the difference in the coordinate system).

Comment: @user19178 I added what I thought might the issue.  If I'm wrong, you might consider expanding your question and clarifying what issue(s) you face.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Reopened on request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question was reopened after I went to bed, so it seems like I left the party early. :)

In any case, `LogPlot[f, <>]` of course is the plot of `Log[f]` with the tick labels and positions adjusted to correspond.  So the slope of the tangent is given by the derivative of `Log[f]`.  Using the variable `x` for my own convenience, the tangent arrow (of length `0.5`) at `x = x0` is given by

```
f = (1 - x)^(-0.5);
f0 = Log[f] /. x -> x0;
df0 = D[Log[f], x] /. x -> x0;
Arrow[{{x0, f0}, {x0, f0} + 0.5 Normalize[{1, df0}]}]
```

The `Arrow` can be added to a plot with [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html), [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html), or using `Show` and `Graphics`.

If you wish to display several arrows of the same geometric length in a plot, they will not appear to have the same length unless `AspectRatio` is set to `Automatic` (or the slopes of the arrows accidentally have the same magnitude).  If you can wait an extra tenth of a second or so, you can fix it so that the arrows will have lengths that will appear the same in the output.  If we let `ar` be the ratio of the aspect ratio of the `PlotRange` to the value of `AspectRatio` (see further down for code), then the length of the tangent should be given by the following to have any arrow appear to have the same length:

```
Arrow[{{x0, f0}, {x0, f0} + 0.5 {1, df0} / Norm[{1, df0*ar}]}]
```

Again, the `0.5` can be adjusted to suit a particular application.

The code for calculating `ar` is based on [Alexey Popkov's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov) [`completePlotRange`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18034/how-to-get-the-real-plotrange-using-absoluteoptions/18040#18040) for computing the actual `PlotRange` of a plot.

```
completePlotRange[plot : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D | _Graph)] := 
 Last@Last@
   Reap[Rasterize[
     Show[plot, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, Ticks -> ((Sow[{##}]; Automatic) &), 
      DisplayFunction -> Identity, ImageSize -> 0], 
     ImageResolution -> 1]]

Block[{f, f0, df0, ar, plot},
 f = (1 - x)^(-0.5);
 f0 = Log[f] /. x -> x0;
 df0 = D[Log[f], x] /. x -> x0;

 plot = LogPlot[f, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.3}, {0.66, 20}}, 
   Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Thick], Automatic}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}, RotateLabel -> False, 
   AspectRatio -> 1
   ];

 ar = If[(AspectRatio /. Options[plot, AspectRatio]) === Automatic,
   1,
   (AspectRatio /. Options[plot, AspectRatio])/
    Ratios[Differences /@ completePlotRange@plot][[1, 1]]
   ];

 Show[
  plot,
  Graphics[{Red, Thick, 
    Table[Arrow[{{x0, f0}, {x0, f0} + 0.5 {1, df0}/Norm[{1, df0*ar}]}], {x0, 0.1, 0.9, 0.2}]}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 for addressing the lengths of the arrows.

Comment: @MichaelE2 late but very instructive...+1...thanks

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Forgot for `LogPlot`.

Firs of all read about [tangent line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent). Then try to uderstand how work function `getTangentVectAtValue`

```
func[t_]:=(1-t)^(-0.5);
getTangentVectAtValue[func_,xValue_,vectLen_]:={{xValue,Log@func[xValue]},{xValue+vectLen,Log[(func[xValue]+(D[func[t],t]/.t->xValue)*(x-xValue))]/.x->(xValue+vectLen)}};

Show[
LogPlot[func[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.66, 20}}, 
  Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}}, ImageSize -> 600, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Thick]}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}, RotateLabel -> False, 
  AspectRatio -> 1], 
 Graphics[Arrow[getTangentVectAtValue[func, 0.8, 0.15]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work on the OP's original plot, which is a `LogPlot`.

Comment: The two most important issues are:1. the slope is tending to infinity near the end where I want to show the arrow; 2. this is a LogPlot. Thank the above answerers!~

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using scaling.  The tangent is drawn at x = 0.8.

```
f[t_] := (1 - t)^(-0.5);
Print@LogPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.66, 20}},
   Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Original plot",
   AspectRatio -> 1];
rescale[i_] := Exp[(i - 1) Log[2.]];
Print[Column[{"Rescaling function: Exp[(i-1) Log[2.]]",
    Row[{"E.g. ", Table[{i, rescale[i]}, {i, 0, 4}]}]}]];
normLog[n_] := 1 + Log[n]/Log[2.];
normf[t_] := normLog[f[t]];
Print@Plot[normf[t], {t, 0, 1},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, normLog /@ {0.66, 20}},
   Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Rescaled plot",
   AspectRatio -> 1];
ndf = D[normf[t], t];
x = 0.8;
m = ndf /. t -> x;
y = normf[x];
c = y - m x;
x2 = x - 0.18;
y2 = m x2 + c;
x3 = x + 0.18;
y3 = m x3 + c;
newticks = {#, Round@rescale[#]} & /@ Range[6];
Print@Show[Plot[normf[t], {t, 0, 1},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, normLog /@ {0.66, 20}},
    Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Plot with tangent",
    AspectRatio -> 1],
   Graphics[Arrow[{{x2, y2}, {x, y}, {x3, y3}}]],
   FrameTicks -> {Automatic, newticks}];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For this specific example but adaptable:

```
fun[t_] := 
 With[{pt = {t, -0.5 Log[1 - t]}, 
   vec = 0.4 Normalize[{1, 0.5/(1 - t)}]},
  Show[LogPlot[(1 - x)^(-0.5), {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0.9, 10}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> 12, 
    PlotLabel -> (1 - x)^(-0.5)], 
   Graphics[{{Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[pt]}, {Thick, 
      Arrowheads[0.1], Arrow[{pt, pt + vec}]}}]]]
Manipulate[fun[u], {u, 0, 0.95}]
```

[image]