# How to correctly show the slope of a linear part on LogPlot

Tags: fitting, logarithmic-scale

I need to plot an [Interpolation function](http://www.wikiupload.com/1D65FL9XPBC7DUV) of one independent variable (only a 3kB file) on `LogPlot` and show the slope of its linear part together on the `LogPlot`, as manually drawn with a dashed red line in the following figure. But when I `Show` the `LogPlot` and a line with the slope of the linear part (see step 3), it turned out to be inconsistent.

1. import data and plot:

   ```
   data = <<"...\\data.m";

   logPlot = LogPlot[data[t], {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0.01, 30000}}, Frame -> True]
   ```

[image]

2. Observe the range of linear part and find a linear fit:

   ```
   lineardata = Table[Log[data[t]], {t, 1, 1.2, 0.02}];

   linearpart = Fit[lineardata, {1, t}, t];
   (*0.923913 + 0.689265 t*)
   ```
3. Show together with the `linearpart`, it was found that the `linearpart` does not parallel to the linear part of the data on `LogPlot`.

   ```
   Show[logPlot, LogPlot[Exp[linearpart], {t, 1, 1.2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]]
   ```

What's wrong with this? Please help. I have updated the code according to the comments. Thanks for @Roman's suggestion.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what doesn't work in step 3 and/or include some sample data so that others can try it themselves?  Maybe you need to use `LogPlot` for `linearpart` too?

Comment: You have to `LogPlot[Exp[linearpart], ...]`

Comment: Your file is broken (after loading it, your code produces errors). Also, don't call two different things `data` (the interpolating function and the list of values).

Comment: Related, tho' a somewhat more complicated problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57437/how-can-i-add-a-tangent-arrow-at-a-certain-point-of-a-curve-in-a-logplot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't realize that you linked to the data in your post, but as @Roman noted, the `InterpolatingFunction` seems broken.  Anyhow, I managed to extract enough to find another problem besides @Roman's comment to use `LogPlot[Exp[linearpart], ...]`.  Specifically, your `Table` doesn't include x-coordinates, so `Fit` assumes they are `1, 2, 3, ...`  Instead try:

```
fdata = Table[{t, Log[data[t]]}, {t, 1, 1.2, 0.02}];
linearpart = Fit[fdata, {1, t}, t];
(* -34.7879 + 35.7638 t *)
Show[logPlot, 
 LogPlot[E^linearpart, {t, 1, 1.2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I have reuploaded the data and corrected the code according to Roman's suggestion.

Comment: @Nobody I made a typo in the definition of `fdata` in my original answer. It's fixed now and should solve your problem.  Sorry about that!

Comment: I think `LogPlot[E^linearpart, ... ]` is equivalent to `Plot[linearpart, ... ]`. About this point, I guess Roman's 1st suggestion is redundant.

Comment: @Nobody Yes, you're right, `Plot[linearpart, ... ]` also works.

Answer (score 6):

`LogPlot` plots $\log y$ vs. $x$, so the slope in the plot is given by 
$$m = {d \over dx} \log y = {dy/dx \over y} \,.$$

If you let `f` be your function, whether that is an `InterpolatingFucntion[...][x]` or some other function, the slope of the tangent to use in the `LogPlot` at `x == x0` will be given by

```
D[f, x]/f /. x -> x0
```

Note that the tangent "line" represents the curve $\log y = \log y_0 + m (x - x_0)$, which is an exponential function. (For the code below, the tangent represents the function `Exp[Log[f] + D[f, x]/f (t - x0)] /. x -> x0`, as a function of `t`.)

Example:

```
Manipulate[
 LogPlot[f, {x, 0, 2},
  Epilog -> {Red, 
    InfiniteLine[{x, Log@f} /. x -> x0, {1, D[f, x]/f /. x -> x0}]},
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True
  ],
 {{f, 0.1 + Exp[50 (x - 1) + 11]/(1 + Exp[50 (x - 1)])}, InputField},
 {{x0, 0.9}, 0, 2}
 ]
```

[image]