# How to draw a tangent line for complex function?

Tags: plotting, complex

I'm new with Mathematica and I have a problem with that, It would be great if you could help me with that.
I try to draw a maximum slope of a plot in the same diagram using resource function tangent line, but it seams that it doesn't work for complex function.

```
ClearAll;
$Assumptions = 
  n ∈ Reals && z ∈ Reals && znew ∈ Reals;

z = Sqrt[2 epsilon] E^(n);
ztwotransitions = Sqrt[2 epsilontwotransitions] E^(n);
znew = Sqrt[2 epsilonnew] E^(n);
epsilon = 
  aminus1^2/(
   18  MPL^2  H0^4) (1 - (aminus1 - aplus)/
       aminus1 E^(-3 (n - n0new)))^2;
epsilontwotransitions = 
  aminus1^2/(
   18  MPL^2  H0^4) (1 - (aminus1 - aplus)/aminus1 E^(-3 (n - n0)))^2;
epsilonnew = 
  astar^2/(18 MPL^2  H0^4) (1 - (astar - aminus2)/
       astar E^(-3 (n - n1)))^2;
modefristsr = 1/Sqrt[2 k] (1 - I/(k τ)) E^(-I k τ);
modefristsrprime = D[modefristsr, τ];
modensr = 
  c1/Sqrt[2 k] (1 - I/(k τ)) E^(-I k τ) + 
   c2/Sqrt[2 k] (1 + I/(k τ)) E^(I k τ);
modensrprime = D[modensr, τ];
modesecondsr = 
  d1/Sqrt[2 k] (1 - I/(k τ)) E^(-I k τ) + 
   d2/Sqrt[2 k] (1 + I/(k τ)) E^(I k τ);
modesecondsrprime = D[modesecondsr, τ];
modefristsrn = Evaluate[modefristsr /. τ -> -1/H0 E^(-n)];
modefristsrprimen = 
  Evaluate[modefristsrprime /. τ -> -1/H0 E^(-n)];
modensrn = Evaluate[modensr /. τ -> -1/H0 E^(-n)];
modensrprimen = Evaluate[modensrprime /. τ -> -1/H0 E^(-n)];
modesecondsrn = Evaluate[modesecondsr /. τ -> -1/H0 E^(-n)];
modesecondsrprimen = 
  Evaluate[modesecondsrprime /. τ -> -1/H0 E^(-n)];
modefristsrn0new = Evaluate[modefristsrn /. n -> n0new];
modefristsrprimen0new = Evaluate[modefristsrprimen /. n -> n0new];
modensrn0new = Evaluate[modensrn /. n -> n0new];
modensrprimen0new = Evaluate[modensrprimen /. n -> n0new];
eqns = {modefristsrn0new - modensrn0new == 0 && 
    modensrprimen0new - modefristsrprimen0new == f0 modensrn0new};
c1c2 = Solve[eqns, {c1, c2}];
solevedmodensrn = modensrn /. c1c2;
modefristsrn0 = Evaluate[modefristsrn /. n -> n0];
modefristsrprimen0 = Evaluate[modefristsrprimen /. n -> n0];
modensrn0 = Evaluate[modensrn /. n -> n0];
modensrprimen0 = Evaluate[modensrprimen /. n -> n0];
eqnswithf2 = {modefristsrn0 - modensrn0 == 0 && 
    modensrprimen0 - modefristsrprimen0 == f2 modensrn0};
c11c21 = Solve[eqnswithf2, {c1, c2}];
solvedfirstslowroll = modefristsrn /. c1c2;
solevedmodensrnnew = modensrn /. c11c21;
solevedmodensrn1 = Evaluate[solevedmodensrnnew /. n -> n1];
solvedmodensrprimen = modensrprimen /. c11c21;
solvedmodensrprimen1 = Evaluate[solvedmodensrprimen /. n -> n1];
modesecondsrn1 = Evaluate[modesecondsrn /. n -> n1];
modesecondsrprimen1 = Evaluate[modesecondsrprimen /. n -> n1];
d1d2 = Solve[
   solevedmodensrn1 - modesecondsrn1 == 0 && 
    modesecondsrprimen1 - solvedmodensrprimen1 == 
     f1 solevedmodensrn1, {d1, d2}];
solevedmodesecondsrn = modesecondsrn /. d1d2;
powerwithc1c2 = k^3/(2 π^2)  (z^(-2)) Abs[solevedmodensrn]^2;
powerwithd1d2 = 
  k^3/(2 π^2)  (znew^(-2)) Abs[solevedmodesecondsrn]^2;
f0 = 3 k0new ( aminus1 - aplus)/aplus;
f1 = 3 k1 (astar - aminus2)/aminus2;
f2 = 3 k0 (aminus - aplus)/aplus;
MPL = 1;
a = E^(n);
k1 = a1 H0;
a0 = E^(n0);
a0new = E^(n0new);
a1 = E^(n1);
τ1 = 0.1;
H0 = 8.8 10^(-7);
σ = 0.01;
astar = 7 10^(-16) MPL^3;
aminus = 7.26 10^(-15) MPL^3;
aplus = 3.35 10^(-14) MPL^3;
deltaa = aminus1 - aplus;
n0 = 10;
n1 = 15;
n0new = 10;
k0 = a0 H0;
k0new = a0new H0;
aminus1 = 7 10^(-16);
aminus2 = 7.26 10^(-15);
LogLogPlot[
 Evaluate[{powerwithc1c2 , powerwithd1d2} /. {k -> k0 kstar, 
    n -> 200}], {kstar, 10^(-1), 1000} , 
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(k\), \(k0\)]\)", 
   "Power_Spectrum"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"one_transition", "Two_transitions"}]
```

[image]

---

**Edited post: This is what should how result should look like:**

[image]

Comment: Do you mean complex as in complex numbers $z=x+iy$? Or complicated?

Comment: I mean complex function as a function with imaginary part @Michael E2

Comment: Then the tangent "line" to $w=f(z)$ is a complex line $w=\alpha z+\beta$, that is in terms of real coordinates, a two-dimensional plane in the four-dimensional space $(w,z)\in{\Bbb C}^2$, no? The only tools we have are `ComplexPlot3D` and `ComplexPlot` - not sure about log-log space. But something like this, maybe: `func = (var^2 + 1)/(var^2 - 1); number = 1 + I;
slope = D[func, var] /. var -> number;
height = func /. var -> number;
ComplexPlot3D[#, {var, -2 - I, 3 + 4 I}] & /@ {func, slope (var - number) + height} // Show`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response but I want to show the tangent line in the diagram so complexplot does not help. I need to indicate the slope of the function in a specific point. @Michael E2

Comment: I see 2 lines, I expect 2 tangent functions, isn't it?

Comment: Just define the real and imaginary parts of the function, and treat them separately.

Comment: What is your specific point?

Comment: yes. there are two functions and I need to show slope for the both @yarchik

Comment: my  specific point is k=k0 @yarchik

Comment: Just define the real and imaginary parts of the function, and treat them separately. it is very hard and complicated to do this @yarchik

Comment: I edited post and added a picture of how result should be look like @Michael E2

Comment: I edited post and added a picture of how result should be look like @yarchik

Comment: Perhaps something like this: `func = Exp[(10 I - 1) t]; number = 1/2;
slope = D[func, t] /. t -> number;
height = func /. t -> number;
ReImPlot[{func, slope (t - number) + height}, {t, 0, 1}(*,ScalingFunctions->{"Log","Log"}*)]` -- if you choose log-log space/scale, lines do not appear as lines (unless the y intercept is 0, in which case they all appear as having slope 1). You might like to have it drawn straight as in your image, but that's a misrepresentation. It can be done however, though it's tricky.

Comment: Here's a related Q&A about tangents and `LogPlot` but about real-valued functions instead of complex-valued ones: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57437/how-can-i-add-a-tangent-arrow-at-a-certain-point-of-a-curve-in-a-logplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example. Linear functions do not have straight graphs under log-log scaling unless they pass through $(0,0)$, in which case their slopes appear as $m=1$ in loglog space.  Note that extra graphics added by hand (such as the red points) have to be scaled by hand.

```
func = (1 + Exp[(10 I + 1) t] + 20 (1 + I) Exp[t^2/10])/(1 + Exp[t^2/10]);
number = 2.5;
slope = D[func, t] /. t -> number;
height = func /. t -> number;

ReImPlot[{func, slope (t - number) + height}, {t, 1, 10}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
 GridLines -> {{number}, {}}, PlotRange -> {1, 50},
 Epilog -> {Red, 
   Point[Thread[{Log@number, Log@ReIm[func /. t -> number]}]]}]
```

[image]

Here's a way to draw the lines incorrectly but straight:

```
ReImPlot[func, {t, 1, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
 GridLines -> {{number}, {}}, PlotRange -> {1, 50},
 Epilog -> {
   Red,
   Point[Thread[{Log@number, Log@ReIm[func /. t -> number]}]],
   ColorData[97][2],
   Riffle[
    {Dashing[{}], Dotted},
    InfiniteLine /@ Transpose@{
       Thread[{Log@t, Log@ReIm[func]} /. t -> number],
       Thread[{Log@t, Log@ReIm[func]} /. 
         t -> number (1 + Sqrt@$MachineEpsilon)]
       }
    ]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

I used a numerical approximation to the apparent slope in scaled loglog space (by taking the line through two nearly adjacent points), because it was easier and good enough for graphing.

Comment: `func = {(9 E^(-2 n)
    H0^4 k^3 MPL^2 Abs[(
     E^((I E^-n k)/
      H0) (1 + (I E^(2 n0new) f0 H0^2)/(2 k^3) + (I f0)/(2 k)) (1 + (
        I E^n H0)/k))/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[k]) - (
     I E^(-((I E^-n k)/H0) + (2 I E^-n0new k)/H0)
       f0 (1 - (I E^n H0)/k) (I E^n0new H0 + k)^2)/(
     2 Sqrt[2] k^(7/2))]^2)/(
  2 aminus1^2 (1 - ((aminus1 - aplus) E^(-3 (n - n0new)))/
     aminus1)^2 \[Pi]^2)}`

Comment: `number = 1;
slope = D[func, k] /. k -> number;
height = func /. k -> number;
ReImPlot[{func, slope (k - number) + height}, {k, 1, 100}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, GridLines -> {{number}, {}}, 
 PlotRange -> {1, 100}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, 
   Point[Thread[{Log@number, Log@ReIm[func /. k -> number]}]]}]`

Comment: Coordinate {0, {Log[
    558016.9319389397 Re[
      2.718281828459045^((-2) $CellContext`n) (1 + 
          46.85714285714286 2.718281828459045^((-3) (-10 + \
$CellContext`n)))^(-2) Abs[
        Complex[-0.0007803515115195993, 
          0.02012192791307727] 2.718281828459045^(Complex[0., 
            103.18165855110193` should be a pair of numbers, 
            or a Scaled or Offset form .

Comment: `Abs` is not differentiable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I write your code and it did not work for my function and it gave the massage above, I don't know what I missed. I wrote the function I'm using.@ Michael E2

Comment: I ticked your answer, thanks for your time, but any suggestion what should I do with Abs?

Comment: @AlirezaMadad So I think this gives the derivative: `number = 1;
slope = D[ComplexExpand@func, n] /. n -> number;
height = func /. n -> number;
ReImPlot[{func, slope (n - number) + height}, {n, 1, 100}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, GridLines -> {{number}, {}},
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[Thread[{Log@number, Log@ReIm[height]}]] /. {_, _DirectedInfinity} -> Nothing}]` -- BUT: There's a lot of numerical noise, which probably messes things up. PLUS: The `slope` is negative which makes the tangent have negative values that cannot be plotted on a log scale....

Comment: ...You needed to change a few things: Instead of `k -> number`, it should have been `n -> number` (right?).  The `PlotRange` worked for my example, but not yours. The `height` is a real number, so its imaginary part is zero, and you can't take the log of it. That's what the `{_, _DirectedInfinity} -> Nothing` is for: to get rid of `Log[0]`, which is infinity.

Comment: it's working now, I'm quiet happy :) but still have problem, number should equal to k0 but it doesn't show the line, I don't know what range I should use. k0=8.8*10^(3)

Comment: This is my code:
ReImPlot[Evaluate[{func, 
    slope (k - number) + height} /. {k -> k0 kstar, 
    n -> 100}], {kstar, 10^(-1), 100}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, GridLines -> {{number}, {}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, 
   Point[Thread[{Log@number, Log@ReIm[height]}]] ColorData[97][2], 
   Riffle[{Dashing[{}], Dotted}, 
     InfiniteLine /@ 
      Transpose@{Thread[{Log@k, Log@ReIm[func]} /. k -> number], 
        Thread[{Log@k, Log@ReIm[func]} /. 
          k -> number (1 + 
              Sqrt@MachinEpsilon)]}] /. {_, _DirectedInfinity} -> 
     Nothing}]